How to save a website with animations locally
I want to save the site pst.net locally, because I liked the animations on it.
I want to view the code locally, but if I save the site using the ctrl+s combination, then the animations are not saved and it does not open properly at all.
Please tell me how I can do this.
I have tried:
Saving it with "ctrl + s";
Saving it with RMB + "save page as"
I want to find a way to save the site to my computer so that I can open it locally and see the same page as on the server.

This sounds like a question for superuser rather than SO


Install a webpage archiver like HTTrack (free, open-source) or WebScrapBook (free, Firefox extension).
Configure the archiver to download the entire website, including all assets (images, CSS, JavaScript files, etc.).
Run the archiver and specify the pst.net website as the target.
Once the archiving process is complete, you'll have a local copy of the website with all its assets.


You need to save each CSS3 file and save them in the same folder as the HTML5 page. You can see CSS3 files in the "Sources" tab of your explorer console.
